# Recibir y ordenar datos de GPS en Raspberry

Tags: python, gps, raspberry-pi

Estoy intentando recibir unos datos de un modulo NEO M6 GPS en mi Raspberry Pi 3 y ya he comprobado que hay comunicación entre ellos. 
Tengo este script en python pero no me funciona. No entiendo de python.

```
import gps

session = gps.gps("localhost", "2947")
session.stream(gps.WATCH_ENABLE | gps.WATCH_NEWSTYLE)
x= 1

while x == 1:
report = session.next()
if report['class'] == 'TPV':
if hasattr(report, 'time'):
print 'Hora: ' + str(report.time)
if hasattr(report, 'lat'):
print 'Latitud: ' + str(report.lat)
if hasattr(report, 'lon'):
print 'Longitud: ' + str(report.lon)
if hasattr(report, 'speed'):
print 'Velocidad: ' + str(report.speed)
if hasattr(report, 'track'):
print 'Rumbo: ' + str(report.track)
if hasattr(report, 'head'):
print report.head
x= 0
```

Pero cuando creo el .py y lo ejecuto mi Raspberry me dice esto

```
File"testgps.py", line 10 
if hasattr(report, 'time'):
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

como puedo hacer para que me funcione este programa o uno parecido?

El programa lo saqué de el foro de Raspberry y parece ser que a la gente si que le funcionaba. Tengo que decir que tengo instalado todo lo que decían ser necesario.
Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un error de identación ya que después de un `if` se espera un bloque de código a ejecutar si se cumple la condición. Tu código carece por completo de identación , no se si lo tienes así o es un problema al copiarlo aquí.

**La identación en Python es crucial**, no es mera estética. Es la forma en la que este lenguaje define los bloques de código, no usa llaves o palabras reservadas (BEGIN, END, etc) como hacen otros lenguajes.

El código debería ser algo así:

```
import gps

session = gps.gps("localhost", "2947")
session.stream(gps.WATCH_ENABLE | gps.WATCH_NEWSTYLE)

x = 1
while x == 1:
    report = session.next()
    if report['class'] == 'TPV':
        if hasattr(report, 'time'):
            print 'Hora: ' + str(report.time)
        if hasattr(report, 'lat'):
            print 'Latitud: ' + str(report.lat)
        if hasattr(report, 'lon'):
            print 'Longitud: ' + str(report.lon)
        if hasattr(report, 'speed'):
            print 'Velocidad: ' + str(report.speed)
        if hasattr(report, 'track'):
            print 'Rumbo: ' + str(report.track)
        if hasattr(report, 'head'):
            print report.head
        x = 0
```

No obstante no estas capturando las posibles excepciones como que el iterador termine sin que se cumpla `if report['class'] == 'TPV'`, algo más general que imprime mientras existan datos disponibles:

```
import gps

session = gps.gps("localhost", "2947")
session.stream(gps.WATCH_ENABLE | gps.WATCH_NEWSTYLE)

while True:
    try:
        report = session.next()
        if report['class'] == 'TPV':
            if hasattr(report, 'time'):
                print 'Hora: ' + str(report.time)
            if hasattr(report, 'lat'):
                print 'Latitud: ' + str(report.lat)
            if hasattr(report, 'lon'):
                print 'Longitud: ' + str(report.lon)
            if hasattr(report, 'speed'):
                print 'Velocidad: ' + str(report.speed)
            if hasattr(report, 'track'):
                print 'Rumbo: ' + str(report.track)
            if hasattr(report, 'head'):
               print report.head
            print

    except KeyError:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        quit()
    except StopIteration:
        session = None
        print "GPSD has terminated"
```

El script imprimirá todos los datos disponibles en el iterador. Puedes detener el script pulsando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> en cualquier momento.

Usa siempre cuatro espacios para identar entre niveles para seguir las recomendaciones de [PEP 8](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) y no uses tabulaciones (si las usaras nunca mezclar con espacios).

El código es válido para Python 2.x.